How to get entire data set from Marvel API
I am fetching data and my pagination buttons seem to be working. I have created a searchCharacters function which filters the data based on the search input, so if I search 'man' I expect all characters that include 'man' to be displayed, but the issue I am having is the searchCharacter function is only filtering data from the 'currentPage' and not the entire dataset of ~1500 odd marvel characters, how would I go about achieving this?
import './style.css'
import javascriptLogo from './javascript.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import { setupCounter } from './counter.js'
import md5 from 'md5'
let resultsPerPage = 10;
let offset = null
let currentPage = 1
const publicKey =  '****';
const privateKey =  '****';
let timestamp = new Date().getTime()
let hashVal =  md5(timestamp+privateKey+publicKey);
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input')
const button = document.getElementById('submit-search');
const main = document.getElementById('main')

const getMarvelCharacters = async function(){

  const url = `http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?`
  const searchparam  =  new URLSearchParams({
    ts : timestamp,
    apikey: publicKey,
    hash:hashVal,
    limit: resultsPerPage,
    offset: offset
  }) 
  const response = await fetch(url + searchparam)
  try {
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error('network response is not okay')
    }
    const data = await response.json()
    const totalNumOfChar = data.data.total
    console.log(totalNumOfChar)
  let characters  = data.data.results

  displayCharacters(characters)
  console.log(characters)
    return characters

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('There was an error:', error)
  }
}

const displayCharacters = function(characters){
  main.innerHTML = ''
  let markup = ''
  characters.forEach(character =>{

    markup +=
    `<div id="results-container">
    <div class="image-container">
    <img src="${character.thumbnail.path}.${character.thumbnail.extension}" alt="">  
    </div>
    <div class="character-info">
    <h2 class="Character-name">${character.name}</h2>
    <p class="character-info">${character.description}</p> 
    </div>
    </div>
    ` 
  });
  main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup) 
  
}
const getPaginationButtonResults = function(){
  const next = document.querySelector('.right')
  const prev = document.querySelector('.left')
  next.addEventListener('click', async (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    currentPage++
    offset+=resultsPerPage
    const characters = await getMarvelCharacters()
    displayCharacters(characters)
  })
  prev.addEventListener('click', async (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    currentPage--
    if(currentPage>0){
      offset-=resultsPerPage
      const characters = await getMarvelCharacters()
      displayCharacters(characters)
    }
  })
}
const searchCharacters =  async function(){

  button.addEventListener('click', async (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    const searchTerm  = searchInput.value.toLowerCase()
    const characters =  await getMarvelCharacters()
    

    const filterChar = characters.filter((character)=>{
      return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    })
    displayCharacters(filterChar)
    return filterChar
  })
}
  getMarvelCharacters()
  getPaginationButtonResults()
  searchCharacters()


For this case, you can use the nameStartsWith parameter.

Looking at the Marvel characters API, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it directly - there's no parameter which would let you search characters whose name contains a phrase / string you specify (for example, typing in man, and expecting both Iron man and Spider-man to be among the results). I guess you could retrieve all of the characters first, store them in an array, and pipe all subsequent user requests through that array first, and then onto the Marvel API.

Yeah, best bet is to cache names locally and that'll be reliably fast for users and easier to implement for you. Otherwise, you need a function to search for the results and iterate through the 0+ pages on each attempt to filter results. It would work, but will inevitably help lead to API quotas during testing or when someone obsessive comes along.
